# seleium firefox driver running memory high after opening windows.

Tags: windows, selenium, firefox, ram

I am running a selenium project that crawls through websites. The project opens links in new pages and checks for content, then closes the opened window. I have noticed that after about 5 minutes of opening windows the ram runs about 3gb out of 4gb for firefox in the task manager. There are other programs running as well, so everything gets slow and starts stalling. I am curious as to why firefox's ram does not reduce after closing the window, but continues to climb. I have tried using firefox cache preferences and sessionstore preferences, but nothing has helped. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or know anything about this? Running selenium 2.53 on firefox 41.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution. Without knowing your exact setup I'm going to explain what fixed the memory leak for me.

I'm running a few extensions in Firefox, Adblock Plus, Auto Refresh, and others. I disabled my extensions to see if that fixed the problem, it did!
Keeping a couple on at once I narrowed it down to Adblock Plus, and found that other people have had memory leaks with it as well, so I switched it out for uBlock Origin. I hope this helps.